# Properly implement erasing from vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

ALL,

I have a following structure

```
struct Definition
{
    std::string schema, name;
    Definition(const std::string &s, const std::string n) : schema(s), name(n) {}
}
```

and I have a following class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        myVector.push_back( "abc", "def" );
        myVector.push_back( "abc", "ghi" );
        myVector.push_back( "abc", "jkl" );
    }
    void EditVector();
private:
    std::vector<Definition> myVector;
};

void Foo::EditVector()
{
    for( auto i = 0; i < somedata.size(); ++i )
    {
        // if somedata[i] is not found inside mtVector name - add it
        // if somedata.size() is less than myVector - remove the extra element
    }
}
```

Now adding the element not found is easy - just do find_if() and if it returns myVector.end() - call push_back().

But what about removing?

I thought I can save myVector to a temporary one, then remove the element from that temporary and finally remove elements from myVector that are left inside the temporary one. But how do I do that?
Or maybe there is a better and more elegant solution?

The somedata is a dynamic vector and its content is not known at the time.

TIA!!

I did see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195217/elegant-way-to-remove-all-elements-of-a-vector-that-are-contained-in-another-vec) but it uses simple/basic type. And maybe there is even more elegant solution.

EDIT:

As apparently something is not clear - here is an explanation.

`somedata` vector contains just the names.

It may have "def" and "ghi" only or it may have "def", "ghi, "jkl", "klm", "nop" and "qrs".

In the first case - "jkl" is not there (see the constructor), so when the function EditVector() ends `myVector` should not contain that element. And in the second case 3 elements should be added to the vector `myVector` with the schema "abc".

EDIT2:

I made it a following function:

```
void RemoveTableFromVector(const std::vector<TableDefinition> &temp)
{
    myVector.erase( std::remove_if( myVector.begin(), myVector.end(),
               [&](const Definition &d)
               {
                     return std::find( temp.cbegin(), temp.cend(), d.name ) == temp.cend();
               } ), myVector.end() );
}
```

and I got the error `binary == no operator found, which takes a left-hand operator of type const Definition (or there is no acceptable conversion).`

Comment: Please explain, what do you want to remove? What is `somedata`? What is an extra element?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `vector `. Maybe something like `set`.

Comment: Please explain why your `EditVector` implementation isn't just `myVector = somedata;`. I'm in agreement with the other comment above - you probably want to be using std::set or std::map (or the unordered variants).

Comment: @selbie, because myvector and somedata may contain different data. Myvector contains set of strings whichanges based on mydata content. However I now realize that after reading the data inside somedata I can simply do: `myvector = somedata`

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the building blocks. `retain_all` algorithm based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195918/6597851):

```
template<class ForwardIt, class InputIt, class Compare = std::less<>>
ForwardIt retain_all(ForwardIt first1, ForwardIt last1,
                     InputIt first2, InputIt last2,
                     Compare comp = std::less{})
{
    auto newEnd = std::remove_if(
        first1, last1,
        [&](const auto& x) {
            while (first2 != last2 && comp(*first2, x))
                ++first2;
            return first2 == last2 || comp(x, *first2);
        });
    return newEnd;
}
```

For `remove_all`, [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) is almost suitable, but it will only remove a value at most as many times as it's present in the second set. I slightly modified the example implementation:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2,
         class OutputIt, class Compare>
OutputIt remove_all_copy(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                         InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                         OutputIt d_first, Compare comp)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        if (first2 == last2)
            return std::copy(first1, last1, d_first);
 
        if (comp(*first1, *first2)) {
            *d_first++ = *first1++;
        } else if (comp(*first2, *first1)) {
            ++first2;
        } else {
            ++first1;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Convenience wrappers that accept containers:

```
template<class C1, class C2, class Compare = std::less<>>
void retainAll(C1& a, const C2& b, Compare cmp = std::less{}) {
    a.erase(
        retain_all(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), cmp),
        a.end());
}

template<class C1, class C2, class Compare = std::less<>>
C1 removeAllCopy(const C1& a, const C2& b, Compare comp = std::less{})
{
    C1 result;
    remove_all_copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(result), comp);
    return result;
}
```

Editing `myVector`:

```
void Foo::EditVector()
{
    std::vector<std::string> somedata{"def", "ghi", "klm"};

    // Comparator that works with any combination of std::strings and Definitions
    auto cmp = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        struct {
            const std::string& operator()(const std::string& x) { return x; }
            const std::string& operator()(const Definition& x) { return x.name; }
        } key;
        return key(a) < key(b);
    };

    // The input need to be sorted
    std::sort(somedata.begin(), somedata.end());
    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), cmp);

    // Delete Definitions whose name is not in somedata
    retainAll(myVector, somedata, cmp);

    // Add new Definitions
    auto toAdd = removeAllCopy(somedata, myVector, cmp);
    for (const auto& name : toAdd) {
        myVector.emplace_back("abc", name);
    }
}
```

Or with only using removal algorithm:

```
// Removal
auto toRemove = removeAllCopy(myVector, somedata, cmp);
myVector = removeAllCopy(myVector, toRemove, cmp);

// Addition
auto toAdd = removeAllCopy(somedata, myVector, cmp);
// range for loop same
```

### Without sorting

Simple, O(nm) solution:

```
// Erase elements
myVector.erase(std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [&](const Definition& d) {
    return std::find(somedata.begin(), somedata.end(), d.name) == somedata.end();
}), myVector.end());

// Add new definitions
for (const std::string& name : somedata) {
    auto it = std::find_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [&](const Definition& d) {
        return d.name == name;
    });
    if (it == myVector.end())
        myVector.emplace_back("abc", name);
}
```

Comment: I understand you are trying to create a generic solution.  `soedata` will contain strings only once. So the first function of `retain_all` should bu sufficient. Also, IIUC, the comparator can be declared as part the class, right? Just trying to expose the least possible stuff...

Comment: Yes, `retain_all` + `std::set_difference` should be sufficient. In earlier design, I used `remove_all` for `myVector` as well, but in the final solution it looks like it's not needed. Comparison operators can be added to the class, but they have to sort first by `name`.

Comment: is there a way to not to se comparators? I don't need those vectors sorted - I'm happy as it is...

Comment: I added a method that doesn't use sorting.

Comment: the modification relies of the `const Definition operator==()` to be present. That's what my MSVC 2017 complains about `no operator found found which takes a left hand operand of type const Definition (or there is no acceptable conversion`.

Comment: What do you mean by "modification"? The code compiles fine for me.

Comment: @kirz, strange.  Did you remove me conparator?

Comment: Which code snippet are you referring to? The original with `retain_all` or the last one that doesn't use sorting? None of this code uses `Definition::operator==`.

Comment: @kirz, I refer to the one without the comparator for deletion.

Comment: @kirz, I added the code I'm trying to compile... Please see my second edit.

Comment: gcc is a little more clear - you code compares `Definition` and `string` inside the `std::find`.

Comment: My code doesn't, but your code compares `TableDefinition` and `string`. What's `TableDefinition`?